# "Function name" is not a function in node js

Tags: node.js

Not able to call from File2 to File1 Function shows below error

Error:bFileReadWirteBack.bdataBack is not a function

File1.Js

```
var bProcess= require('./File2'); 

bProcess.pushData({json:true,body: bodyData});

module.exports={
        
    bdataBack(incount,pageLimit){
        console.log("callback count:"+incount);
        console.log("callback Limit:"+pageLimit);
    }
    
}
```

File2.Js

```
var bFileReadWirteBack= require('./File1');


bFileReadWirteBack.bdataBack(first,last);

module.exports = {
    pushData(req, res) {
                
        ---------
}
```

Comment: Wait, isn't this illegal you are requiring both of them in each other, eventually, you're in a kind of loop, in which no file is really ready for export.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar: there are multiple ways circular dependencies can be implemented.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar: Please help me with solution,Thank you

Comment: @venugopal I am sorry mate if you need circular dependencies, I don't have any idea, though.